# Use RegExp in Awk

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk

I have CSV file:

```
<iframe src="https://localhost/get/44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35"></iframe>|name_1
<iframe src="https://localhost/get/5db0d477d707121934ff"></iframe>|name_2
<iframe src="https://localhost/get/6c95bd2b32ed45989c61"></iframe>|name_3
<iframe src="https://localhost/get/0a9c4655800e8a7b9ea2"></iframe>|name_4
<iframe src="https://localhost/get/754953b57a32e2841bda"></iframe>|name_5
```

and want use RegExp and Awk (or Gawk) to make this CSV file like this:

```
44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35|name_1
5db0d477d707121934ff|name_2
6c95bd2b32ed45989c61|name_3
0a9c4655800e8a7b9ea2|name_4
754953b57a32e2841bda|name_5
```

I have worked RegExp in Grep

```
$ grep -Po "[A-Za-z]*+\d++\w++" example.txt 
44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35
5db0d477d707121934ff
6c95bd2b32ed45989c61
0a9c4655800e8a7b9ea2
754953b57a32e2841bda
```

but this RegExp not work in Awk. I think i'm not correct use regexp in Awk or this type of RegExp not worked in Awk.

```
$ awk -F "|" 'match($1, /[A-Za-z]*+\d++\w++/, a) {print a[0]"|"$2}' example.txt 
db0d477d707121934ff|name_2
bd2b32ed45989c61|name_3
bda|name_5
```

Just Awk work fine:

```
$ awk -F "|" '{print $1"|"$2}' example.txt 
<iframe src="https://localhost/get/44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35"></iframe>|name_1
<iframe src="https://localhost/get/5db0d477d707121934ff"></iframe>|name_2
<iframe src="https://localhost/get/6c95bd2b32ed45989c61"></iframe>|name_3
<iframe src="https://localhost/get/0a9c4655800e8a7b9ea2"></iframe>|name_4
<iframe src="https://localhost/get/754953b57a32e2841bda"></iframe>|name_5
```

Comment: `[A-Za-z]*+\d+\w+`?

Comment: $ awk -F "|" 'match($1, /[A-Za-z]*+\d+\w+/, a) {print a[0]"|"$2}' example.txt 
db0d477d707121934ff|name_2
bd2b32ed45989c61|name_3
bda|name_5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F'<iframe src="https://localhost/get/|"></iframe>' '{print $2 $3}' file
44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35|name_1
5db0d477d707121934ff|name_2
6c95bd2b32ed45989c61|name_3
0a9c4655800e8a7b9ea2|name_4
754953b57a32e2841bda|name_5
```

This works by setting the input field separator to be *either* `iframe src="https://localhost/get/` or `"></iframe>` in which case the output you want is the second field followed by the third field.

#### Alternative Method Using Match

```
$ awk -F "|" 'match($1, /[[:xdigit:]]{20}/, a) {print a[0]"|"$2}' file
44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35|name_1
5db0d477d707121934ff|name_2
6c95bd2b32ed45989c61|name_3
0a9c4655800e8a7b9ea2|name_4
754953b57a32e2841bda|name_5
```

Note that awk supports POSIX regular expressions.  That means that it recognizes character classes like `[[:digit:]]` or `[[:alnum:]]` but not necessarily `\d` or `\w`.  As a GNU-specific extension, gawk supports `\w` (but not `\d`).  For portability, stick to the POSIX classes as shown in `man 7 regex`.

#### Yet another method

Your regex `[A-Za-z]*+\d++\w++` can be translated into awk as follows:

```
$ awk -F "|" 'match($1, /[[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:alnum:]]+/, a) {print a[0]"|"$2}' file
44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35|name_1
5db0d477d707121934ff|name_2
6c95bd2b32ed45989c61|name_3
0a9c4655800e8a7b9ea2|name_4
754953b57a32e2841bda|name_5
```

Note that this method requires that the 20-character hex string contains at least one digit.

Comment: Thank you for answer, this work! But i want understand why my regexp work not corrent and how can I make the code that will work with my type of RegExp.  It can be possible to use maybe grep on top/with Awk ?

Comment: @Peter_Media OK.  I just updated the answer with a method that uses your regex.

Comment: it's highly unlikely but possible to have all alpha, so I think only correct one is using `[:xdigit:]`

Comment: @karakfa That is absolutely true (and noted in my answer) but, as you can see here in the comments, the OP wanted to see how to make his regex work in awk.

Answer (score 0):

1. The difference between awk and grep invocations in your example is -P option in grep, which stands for "Use Perl regexp". If you replace it with -E, it will work just like your awk run. Awk does not support Perl extension.
2. Your regexp is better be fixed, I don't think you need these extra + signs, to begin with. If I can assume that you need all letters or digits after get/ then I'd rather write:

   awk -F "|" 'match($1, /get/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/, a) {print a[1]"|"$2}' example.txt

Here we use [A-Za-z0-9]+ match any number of small or upper letters or digits that come after /get, use a[1] to print a matched group inside the parentheses instead of the whole matching pattern a[0] which includes get/

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/<.*get\//,"")gsub(/".*e>/,"")}1'  file

44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35|name_1
5db0d477d707121934ff|name_2
6c95bd2b32ed45989c61|name_3
0a9c4655800e8a7b9ea2|name_4
754953b57a32e2841bda|name_5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
awk -F"[/\">|]" 'BEGIN{ OFS = "|" }{ print $6, $11 }' yourfile
```

With the -F option in the beginning the Field Separator can be /, ", > and |. After that is done you can just print the fields $6 and $11 which contain your desired output together with the output field separator.

Output:

```
44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35|name_1
5db0d477d707121934ff|name_2
6c95bd2b32ed45989c61|name_3
0a9c4655800e8a7b9ea2|name_4
754953b57a32e2841bda|name_5
```